# Opening existing PowerPoint from a directory with Python 3.5

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Open an existing PowerPoint Presentation from a directory
Example from here: [Charts from Excel to PowerPoint with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639900/charts-from-excel-to-powerpoint-with-python)

My situation is different - the link showed how to to open a new presentation not a saved existing one.

error message:

> module None.

Comment: I recommend you update with your OS and platform details.  Doing this on Linux would be very different than Windows

Comment: I am using windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can call out to the `open` cmd and pass the filename to be opened as the only parameter. It will query the registry to find the program that should be used as default to open such a file, how to do it, and then do it.

This should work, did not check though

```
subprocess.run(['open', 'the file to be opened.pptx'])
```

**Update**: There is also https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile

Comment: I am opening it to add excel charts and graphs and text and tables to it. I don't know if the language you are using will help with doing that.

Comment: I was under the impression that by "opening" you mean "present to the user".  [Here](http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/) is an example of how to use win32com to open an existing pptx and modify it.

Comment: Ok - but how do you open it from a saved directory.  I saw that link before and I was trying to figure out this argument Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(sys.argv[1]) and how to put the path and filename there ?

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` refers to the first argument given to the script while executing; that is `python foobar.py openme.pptx` would open `openme.pptx`. Replace the parameter to `Open()` with a string or a variable holding your filename

Comment: actually I did that and couldn't open it. I think maybe I need to install python-pptx ?  The error I got is pywintypes.com_error:  (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024773), None)

Comment: Do you think I need to install python-pptx package ?

Comment: I can't tell, the error is most unhelpful. `win32com` should work, though. You may want to google for 'win32com powerpoint' and see if there are more knobs to be turned. `python-pptx` seem capable as well.

Comment: I could open excel no problem but that error always comes up when I try to open powerpoint.