# AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'Shapes'

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

Given below is the code I'm running. What I'm trying to achieve is simple. I need to copy a chart from an existing Excel file & paste as a chart (NOT image) into an existing PowerPoint slide.

But I always get the error

> "AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'Shapes'"

Is there any package I'm supposed to install?

```
from pptx import Presentation
import xlrd
import math
import xlutils

import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants

prs = Presentation('D:\Sruti K\Online_Retail\APAC\Office Slides\Office QBU Slides\FY17 Q4 June\Office Slides FY17 Q4 test.pptx')
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[3]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)

book = xlrd.open_workbook(r'D:\Sruti K\Online_Retail\APAC\Office Slides\Office QBU Slides\FY17 Q4 June\Python Chart Paste.xlsx')
ws = book.sheet_by_index(0)

sheetsinbook=[book.sheet_by_index(0)]


for ws in sheetsinbook:
    for chart in ws.Shapes():
        chart.Activate()
        chart.Copy()
        slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(constants.ppPasteShape)
        Print("hi")

prs.save(r'D:\Sruti K\Online_Retail\APAC\Office Slides\Office QBU Slides\FY17 Q4 June\Python Trial APAC PPT V1.pptx')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are capitalizing random words, which changes what they do/call. For example you typed `Print` instead of `print` which is not valid unless you have a *class* named Print. If you use `ws.shapes()` instead it should work (and un-capitalize some of those other words too).

Comment: Hi Cary! I have done this but I'm still getting the same error. I'm using the 2.7.13 version. Could it be because of this? I have also tried the code posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639900/charts-from-excel-to-powerpoint-with-python  but this throws up a similar error as well.

Comment: Did you try `for chart in ws.ChartObjects`?

Comment: Hey Cary! AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'ChartObjects' is what I'm seeing here. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're calling for COM API inside `python-pptx` which does not have that.

What you need to do is use `win32com.client` instead of `python-pptx`, you can refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/powerpoint/object-model) (but this one is for VB, but it got almost the same implementation for python) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.pastespecial)'s for your `PasteSpacial`

I use `Paste` instead of `PasteSpecial` for the example:

```
import win32com.client
import pyperclip

Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = Application.Presentations.Add()
Slide = Presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
pyperclip.copy('Some text.')
Slide.Shapes.Paste()
```

Hope this helps.