# How to copy a range from an Excel File and paste that range into a Powerpoint slide using Python?

Tags: python, excel, powerpoint, win32com

I'd like to copy a range from an excel document into a powerpoint slide.

This is my attempt after reading through [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639900/charts-from-excel-to-powerpoint-with-python) :

```
import win32com.client

powerpoint_object = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
powerpoint_object.visible = True
powerpoint_presentation = powerpoint_object.Presentations.Open("example_powerpoint.pptx")


excel_object = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel_object.visible = True
excel_workbook = excel_object.Workbooks.Open(Filename="example_excel.xlsx")
excel_worksheet = excel_workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
excel_range = excel_worksheet.Range("A1:L100")
excel_range.Copy()

powerpoint_slide = powerpoint_presentation.Slides.Add(1,12)
powerpoint_slide.Shapes().Paste()
```

However I get the following error:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this error is caused by the lack of full file paths. Try replacing `"example_powerpoint.pptx"` and `"example_excel.xlsx"` with their full paths.